# How to change the href of buttons with jquery

Tags: jquery

```
<a class="btn conversation" href="/contact1"> </a>
<a class="btn conversation" href="/contact2"> </a>
<a class="btn conversation" href="/contact3"> </a>
```

I have a number of buttons with a special *conversation* class. I would like to attach the value `?open_deals` to all these buttons's href attribute.

```
$('.conversation').attr('href', $('.conversation').attr('href') + '?open_deals');
```

I have tried this but all of the buttons get the href value: `/contact1?open_deals`

I think I have to use `$(this)` when setting the value. Not sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`attr` accepts a function, jQuery internally iterates through the selected elements, first parameter is the index and second one is the current attribute's value of each element.

```
$('.conversation').attr('href', function(i, current){
     return current + '?open_deals'
})
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution :

```
$('.conversation').each(function(){this.href += '?open_deals'});
```

[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/dLcHW/)

Answer (score 0):

Pass a function to the [`attr` method](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#computed-attr-values):

```
$('.conversation').attr('href', function (i, val) {
    return val + '?open_details';
});
```